# Pivot table number format based on title

Tags: vba, excel

Working with this:

```
For Each pvtFld In Pvt.DataFields
    If pvtFld.Name = "*Rate*" Then
     pvtFld.NumberFormat = "0.00%"
       Else: pvtFld.NumberFormat = "#,##0"
    End If
Next pvtFld
```

So that for each field in a pivot table, if the pivot field name contains "Rate" it will format as a percent, otherwise a number.

The code runs correctly without any stops or errors, but the resulting table still shows values as a number format. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Also attempted:

```
For Each pvtFld In Pvt.DataFields
    If pvtFld.Name = "*" & "Rate" & "*" Then
     With pvtFld
     .NumberFormat = "0.00%"
     End With
       Else:
        With pvtFld
        .NumberFormat = "#,##0"
        End With
    End If
Next pvtFld
```

This also loops through fluidly, but numbers  in columns with "Rate" in the title do not format correctly.

Comment: did you try to refresh chart (even manually)?

Comment: Sorry, not a chart, the table. So I'm generating a whole table with other existing code, but I need to format different columns as either a % or #, and that will change by the name of the column: i.e. "Rate".

Comment: generally your code looks ok. Go with F8 key in debug mode to check if `if statement` is correct

Comment: Yeah, this `For Each PivotField In Pvt.PivotFields
    If PivotField.Name = "*Rate*" Then
     With PivotField
     PivotField.NumberFormat = "0.00%"
     End With
       Else:
        With PivotField
        PivotField.NumberFormat = "#,##0_"
        End With
    End If
Next PivotField`  I still get an error on the `PivotField.NumberFormat = "#,##0_"` Line.

Answer (score 0):

Looks as though by using the `Like` command, I was able to get it to recognize the field to contain the word "Rate"

Solution:

```
For Each pvtFld In Pvt.DataFields
    If pvtFld.Name Like "*Rate*" Then
     pvtFld.NumberFormat = "0.00%"
       Else: pvtFld.NumberFormat = "#,##0"
    End If
Next pvtFld
```